# Cassandra 2.1 CQL error creating table with tuple: no viable alternative at input '>'

Tags: cassandra, cql, cassandra-2.0

It's probably something really stupid... but I can't create a table with the new tuple type:

```
cqlsh:ta> CREATE TABLE tuple_test (k int PRIMARY KEY, v frozen <tuple<int, int>> );
Bad Request: line 1:68 no viable alternative at input '>'
cqlsh:ta>
```

I've pretty much copied the table creation statement from the DataStax docs... What am I missing?

thanks!

Update - based on help from BryceAtNetwork23 and RossS:

Yes, you are right - I had DataStax Enterprise which had Cassandra 2.0.

I have installed DataStax Community with Cassandra 2.1 and all worked fine!

One note:  skipping the 'frozen' keyword does not work with the DSC's Cassandra distribution - but having the frozen in does work. Thanks for your help!

```
[cqlsh 4.1.1 | Cassandra 2.1.2 | DSE  | CQL spec 3.1.1 | Thrift protocol 19.39.0]
cqlsh> CREATE TABLE ta.tuple_test (k int, v tuple<int, int>,PRIMARY KEY(k) );
Bad Request: Non-frozen tuples are not supported, please use frozen<>
cqlsh> CREATE TABLE ta.tuple_test (k int, v frozen <tuple<int, int>>,PRIMARY KEY(k) );
cqlsh>
```

Comment: Marina, thanks for the info on the `frozen` keyword.  It might have worked for me that way because my sandbox (here at work) is still running on a 2.1 release candidate.  I'll upgrade and give it another shot, as well.

Comment: Tried your original `CREATE` on my home 2.1.2 cluster, and it works just fine (see edit).

Comment: Great :) I also had to upgrade my DataStax driver to 2.1.4 (I had 2.1.2 before) - to get around the guava lib version conflict - but that's a different issue. It all works fine now. thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That *is* weird.  I get the same error.  I did manage to get it to work with a slight modification or two.  I then did a `desc` just to make sure that it created ok:

```
aploetz@cqlsh> CREATE TABLE stackoverflow.tuple_test (k int, v tuple<int, int>,PRIMARY KEY(k) );

aploetz@cqlsh> use stackoverflow ;
aploetz@cqlsh:stackoverflow> desc table tuple_test ;

CREATE TABLE stackoverflow.tuple_test (
    k int PRIMARY KEY,
    v frozen<tuple<int, int>>
) WITH bloom_filter_fp_chance = 0.01
    AND caching = '{"keys":"ALL", "rows_per_partition":"NONE"}'
    AND comment = ''
    AND compaction = {'min_threshold': '4', 'class': 'org.apache.cassandra.db.compaction.SizeTieredCompactionStrategy', 'max_threshold': '32'}
    AND compression = {'sstable_compression': 'org.apache.cassandra.io.compress.LZ4Compressor'}
    AND dclocal_read_repair_chance = 0.1
    AND default_time_to_live = 0
    AND gc_grace_seconds = 864000
    AND max_index_interval = 2048
    AND memtable_flush_period_in_ms = 0
    AND min_index_interval = 128
    AND read_repair_chance = 0.0
    AND speculative_retry = '99.0PERCENTILE'
```

The main thing, is that I didn't specify `frozen` in my `CREATE`, but when you `desc` the table, you can see that it knew to put it there.

Edit- Here is my `cqlsh` spec:

```
[cqlsh 5.0.1 | Cassandra 2.1.0-rc5-SNAPSHOT | CQL spec 3.2.0 | Native protocol v3]
```

> Cassandra 2.0.11.83

Hmm...based on this, I don't know that you're actually on Cassandra 2.1.  And I'm pretty sure that the Tuple type is a 2.1 and higher feature.  Double check your Cassandra version once.  Also, if you're on DSE (which means you have support) I'd open up a ticket with them, describing the error that you're seeing.

Edit- FYI, I have upgraded my 2.1.0-rc5 version to 2.1.2, and run your original `CREATE`, and it works as-is:

```
Connected to PermanentWaves at 127.0.0.1:9042.
[cqlsh 5.0.1 | Cassandra 2.1.2 | CQL spec 3.2.0 | Native protocol v3]
Use HELP for help.
aploetz@cqlsh> use stackoverflow ;
aploetz@cqlsh:stackoverflow> CREATE TABLE tuple_test (k int PRIMARY KEY, v frozen <tuple<int, int>> );
aploetz@cqlsh:stackoverflow> desc table tuple_test ;

CREATE TABLE stackoverflow.tuple_test (
    k int PRIMARY KEY,
    v frozen<tuple<int, int>>
)...
```

Comment: thank you, @BryceAtNetwork23 !! However, it still does not work for me in my cqlsh... I took your exact create stmt - and still am getting the same error. Now I started suspecting that maybe the version of 'cqlsh' shipped with the latest DataStax Enterprise 4.6 is not a correct one and does not understand Cassandra2.1... Here is the spec of my 'cqlsh': [cqlsh 4.1.1 | Cassandra 2.0.11.83 | DSE 4.6.0 | CQL spec 3.1.1 | Thrift protocol 19.39.0]  Could you let me know what yours is?  Thank you!

Comment: DSE 4.6 doesn't ship with Cassandra 2.1, only 2.0.11.83 so this is probably why the example doesn't work.

Comment: Thanks @RussS, I thought so.